# use AudioUnit initialize in all viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i am working on app in which i refer the aurioTouch application from apple to show the waveforms.
 it is requirement that i have to show the waveforms at top of every viewcontrollers.
so, i setup AudioUnit in firstViewController's viewDidLoad method.

```
    XThrowIfError(AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, rioInterruptionListener, self), "couldn't initialize audio session");

    UInt32 audioCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord;
    XThrowIfError(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(audioCategory), &audioCategory), "couldn't set audio category");
    XThrowIfError(AudioSessionAddPropertyListener(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, propListener, self), "couldn't set property listener");

    Float32 preferredBufferSize = .005;
    XThrowIfError(AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration, sizeof(preferredBufferSize), &preferredBufferSize), "couldn't set i/o buffer duration");

    UInt32 size = sizeof(hwSampleRate);
    XThrowIfError(AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_CurrentHardwareSampleRate, &size, &hwSampleRate), "couldn't get hw sample rate");

    XThrowIfError(AudioSessionSetActive(true), "couldn't set audio session active\n");

    XThrowIfError(SetupRemoteIO(rioUnit, inputProc, thruFormat), "couldn't setup remote i/o unit");
```

Here i can able to show the waveforms of input sounds, 
Now **when i click on secondTab, in FirstviewController's viewWillDisappear method  I am stopping the AudioUnit.**

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:YES];
AudioOutputUnitStop(rioUnit);
AudioUnitUninitialize(rioUnit);
AudioSessionSetActive(false);
  //[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(disposeCoreAudio) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
//[eaglView stopAnimation];
}
```

in secondViewController i am again try to initialize AudioUnit

```
XThrowIfError(AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, rioInterruptionListener, self), "couldn't initialize audio session");
```

but it shows exception:
**about to throw 'init': couldn't initialize audio session
Error: couldn't initialize audio session ('init')**

In first viewController I am able to stop the instance of AudioUnit but not able to Initialize it again in secondViewController.
  Can anyone help me to come out of this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have your audio unit be controlled of the view controller, make a singleton controller that deals only with it. Then you can get the shared instance of that controller from any audio unit.

BTW, I can strongly recommend using [Novacaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine) in that controller, it makes audio units much more fun to work with: less C++, more ObjC. :-)